# Xamarin Forms pin entry - use Android / iOS entry as default?

Tags: c#, android, ios, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm building a cross platform app in Xamarin Forms which requires users to enter a pin to authenticate.
At the moment I have built my own pin entry page in XAML, but although it works I wonder is there a way from code-behind to bring up the android / ios pin entry as the default when the page opens?

Comment: I don´t think that is a good idea. Anyone with the pin will be able to open your app. Having say that I think that Android or IOS will not expose that information to your app

Comment: Ah see what you mean, I'm looking more for something to capture pin input and authenticate against the user pin held in a SQL DB, so maybe not the best thing to use.